# safeboot + grub

Tags: linux, windows

I have Safeboot already installed in windows and I created a new partition, then installed ubuntu in the new partition.

Now I can't boot into Safeboot-encrypted windows.

How to I boot to Safeboot-encrypted Windows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It *sounds* like safeboot had something installed to the mbr (master boot record, or something) that kicked off the decryption process of the windows partition (I'm assuming the entire windows partition is encrypted). Installing ubuntu/grub probably overwrote whatever was in the mbr, so now you can't decrypt your windows partition on boot.

Off the cuff, I would say that your windows partition is screwed, but you may be able to hassle mcafee enough to get some help on that front, either getting your data off the partition or restoring a working bootloader for windows.

Note: If you CAN get a bootloader for your windows partition, make sure to install it on that particular partition (in linux speak, install the bootloader on /dev/sda1 instead of /dev/sda) so you can continue to dual-boot with grub.